# Entity Framework Code first creates duplicate foreign key for the same propery in the nested classes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations, ef-fluent-api

Entity Framework Code first creates duplicate foreign key for the same property in the nested classes with One-to-zero relation.

Example:

```
abstract class A {}

public class MyClass {}

public class B:A {  
    ...

    public int MyClassId {get; set;}

    public virtual MyClass MyClass { get; set;}
}

public class C:A {
    ...

    public int MyClassId {get; set;}

    public virtual MyClass MyClass { get; set;}
}
```

Class B and A points to the same table **A** in DB.

I have next configuration for both of them

```
modelBuilder.Entity<B>().HasRequired(x => x.MyClass).WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.MyClassId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<C>().HasRequired(x => x.MyClass).WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.MyClassId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

And the problem is that EF creates in the table **A** two columns **MyClassId** ans **MyClassId1** instead of one.

What I need to change to have only one column **MyClassId** ?

I can't move MyClass property to the class A, because there are many classes which a nested from A and the shouldn't have this property.
Also I can't create a proxy class between A and B,C.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just move `public int MyClassId` and `public virtual MyClass MyClass` to `A` class?

Comment: There are about 10 nested class from A and they should not have MyClass property.

Comment: In this case you will have a table of "sparse matrix" type, that is lots of null cells.

Comment: @tschmit007 it's not a problem in this case.

Answer (score 0):

you must:

```
public class ConcreteA : A {
    public int MyClassId {get; set;}
    public virtual MyClass MyClass { get; set;}
}
```

and then

```
public class B:ConcreteA {  
...

}
```

same with C.

---

this is not a problem/bug. This is a feature.

You can read about TPH here: http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph

Basically you choose to use Table Per Inheritance, that is isolate you properties by class, but having all of them in the same Db Table.

One can also says: (A)B == (A)C, but as MyClass is not part of A => B.MyClass <> C.MyClass

Comment: Could you please provide information why the problem happened?

Comment: read my last edit to the question. I cant move it to A and make kind of a proxy class 'A'.

Comment: Is there any way to map it to the same column in table A. without creating a duplicate columns?

Comment: Not really but maybe: A -> AA (your property here)-> B, C, and for the other classes A ->D,E,F...

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use the proxy class.